# Serving static files with spaces in file names with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've found a very strange behavior in Spring Boot when trying to serve static files with spaces (or any other special chars, like accents) in file names.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.6.1 with Spring Web MVC and the following customization:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/repo/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:///srv/intranet/repo/");
    }
}
```

I have two files under `/srv/intranet/repo`, named `foo.txt` and `foo bar.txt` (note the space in the second file name).

When I start my application, I can access the first file at `http://localhost:8080/repo/foo.txt`. But I cannot access the second file (the one with the space in the file name) at `http://localhost:8080/repo/foo%20bar.txt` (I get a 404 error).

BUT if I put the file `foo bar.txt` under `src/main/resources/static`, then I can acces the file at `http://localhost:8080/foo%20bar.txt`.

I'm aware that Spring Boot [configures several directories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content) by default to serve static content (one of them being `classpath:/static/`), so I'm wondering: what is the difference between the preconfigured directories and the one I'm adding in my @Configuration class via `addResourceHandler().addResourceLocations()`? Am I missing some details when adding the new resourceHandler?

**WORKAROUND**

You can set the following property in your `application.properties` (or equivalent .yml) to get the old behavior in Spring Boot (pre-v2.6.0):

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

**UPDATE**

I believe this is probably a bug in `PathPattern`, which replaces `AntPathMatcher`, and was introduced in Spring Framework 5.3 and adopted in Spring Boot 2.6.0. [I submitted a bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28939).

**UPDATE (2022-06-04)**

The bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27791). The fix will be included in Spring Framework 5.3.21.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this issue.

Just add the following in your Spring Boot configuration file `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

The [documentation for this property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.1/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy) states that `ant-path-matcher` is the default value, but it is not. The [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/756b9b9254ec4b09f46aba110ca837b50f7d7a92/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcProperties.java#L404) shows that the default value is `path-pattern-parser`. I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28936).

Comment: Further investigation shows that this behavior changed when upgrading my application from Spring Boot v2.5.6 to v2.6.0 (If I test my application using v2.5.7, it works as expected). More precisely, the change was added in v2.6.0-M3. See [issue 24805](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24805)

Answer (score 1):

I have following configuration with Spring Boot 2.6.1 and it successfully loads file with a space in name.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.sw" }) 
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**").addResourceLocations("file:D:/img/");
    }
}
```

I have an image with name "SO 1.png" (note the space). When hitting the application I get the image

[image]

[image]

You can probably troubleshoot by putting Spring web on TRACE level where it emits below information while serving the file.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet=TRACE
```

Below are the logs

```
2021-12-07 14:24:24.544 TRACE 17200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/files/SO%201.png", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-12-07 14:24:24.568 TRACE 17200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [URL [file:D:/img/]]] and 3 interceptors
2021-12-07 14:24:24.580 TRACE 17200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
2021-12-07 14:24:24.626 TRACE 17200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2021-12-07 14:24:24.626 DEBUG 17200 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shailendra. I noticed that you annotated your class with `@EnableWebMvc`. That's the only difference between your example and mine. If I add that annotation, then everything works, and I can retrieve files with spaces in their names!

Anyway, Spring Boot documentation states that, [by using `@EnableWebMvc`, all Spring MVC autoconfiguration provided by Spring Boot will be disabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.auto-configuration), which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

in Spring 5 a new [PathPatternParser](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html) was introduced

try replacing

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
```

with:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/files/{*path}")
```

Comment: Thanks @ezer. It didn't work. It's a known bug in PathPatternParser. I submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28939) and I'm waiting for a fix.